# Special characters SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, listview, uwp

I have an UWP project and I'm using SQLite.

The ListView and its ItemSource is produced by this code: `conn.Table<MyTable().ToListAsync();`

I want to get only objects that satisfy the following condition:

```
private async void myListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Name = '{0}'", (e.AddedItems[0] as MyTable).Name);
   myListView.ItemsSource = conn.QueryAsync<MyTable>(sql);
}
```

It's okay, working fine, BUT if the name has special characters as "á,é,í,ó,ú" for example, it doesn't work, I don't know why.

Examples: "Jón, Ján"..

Comment: There is an encoding problem somewhere in your code.

Comment: Can you give me more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work, I think it's a specific problem with that `format` method of `string` with special characters.

**Solution:**

```
private async void myListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   myListView.ItemsSource = conn.Table<MyTable>().Where(b => b.MyParam == (e.AddedItems[0] as MyTable).MyParam).ToListAsync();
}
```